# Jooq for different enviornment

Tags: mysql, java-8, jooq

I am using Jooq with Mysql in my application.Our release pipeline follow dev -> stage -> prod .

Every env has the same schema but the problem is, they might have the following variables:

1. **They might have different database name (dev_db,stage_db,prod_db)**
2. **They might have different DB URL and credentials**

Currently, I am ended up with the following code.

```
public static void init() {

    Target l_target =   new Target();
    System.out.println("My directory is::"+l_target.getPackageName());
    l_target.setDirectory("src/main/java");
    l_target.setPackageName("com.my.paas.css.entity");
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                    .withDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    .withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/paas")
                    .withUser("root"))
            .withGenerator(new Generator()
                    .withDatabase(new Database()
                            .withName("org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase")
                            .withIncludes(".*")
                            .withExcludes("")
                            .withInputSchema("paas"))
                    .withTarget(l_target));

    try {
        GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to understand, How can I make code generation adaptable with the environment?

Answer (score 0):

#### Programmatic configuration

You're already using the programmatic code generation configuration, so making adaptations to your configuration elements should be trivial. For example, in order to select the right JDBC URL for your given database connection, you will use a local variable or method instead of hard coding the URL:

```
// Instead of
.withUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/paas")

// write...
.withUrl(jdbcUrl())
```

And implement `jdbcUrl()` depending on the environment.

#### Mapping schemas

Another feature set you might want to look into is the schema mapping feature, which you can apply:

- [during code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/)
- [at runtime](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping/)

Notice, it's not unusual to check in generated code and build a library from it, rather than re-generating the code on each environment.

Comment: How can we generate during code generation? We have a Jenkins job for the build process. We don't have DB access from Jenkins server (where actually code generation is going on)?

Comment: @SandeepPandey: Would you mind asking a new question? Your new question isn't really related to this one.